# VS Code: How to open referenced code in new tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**In VS Code:**

Lets say, e.g. I am inside a React component file. From here, I click on another React child component with Cmd + mouseclick (on Mac).

**I expect this clicked component to open a new tab** in VS Code. Instead it opens a popup / preview view of the component file.

I tried to set various preview settings to false, most promising seemed this one:

`"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

But it did not change behaviour.

Comment: Does F12 do what you describe?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? (read that this is related)